# Inkscape .pdf_tex help - alignment and scaling of objects

Tags: inkscape

Started learning Inkscape for thesis figure generation. I've got a few questions about alignment and scaling of objects.

Files:
[svg](http://www.mediafire.com/file/x5q745y5wbcf62s/file), [pdf](http://www.mediafire.com/file/d3is1q6zvc54fzf/file), [pdf_tex](http://www.mediafire.com/file/2fgqtz2ro0i2kik/file), [mwe.pdf](http://www.mediafire.com/file/nfy56hs1t6rodvi/file).

Images if you don't want to download the files:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksppi.jpg. Img 1 is within Inkscape, img 2 is in mwe.pdf

I have a MWE.tex for testing this which I use:

```
\begin{figure}
\input{<figure_name>.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
```

My figure is present in mwe.pdf however it's pushed very far to the right, even adding in `\centering` before the input command doesn't seem to fix it.
**Edit**: The image being off center was solved by changing `Output page size` to `Use exported objects size`.

I'm also having alignment issues with the text and the scale bars. What I want to happen is for the text to be aligned with the right of the scale bar, as seen in the svg/inkscape image C and D. I use the align tool to align them both relative to one another but this doesn't seem to work. I believe I somehow need to change the anchor point of the text box, ideally to the bottom right. **Edit**: Went to V0.92 and found the text align button. Unsure where it's hidden in V1.0. that solved the issue.

The scale of the figure labels, A-F, is also different. This is expected as the text size conforms to the tex document. How do I configure it so the white box scales with the text?

Thanks for the help!

Edit: changed file hosting location

Comment: The pdf file has several pages, which seems bizarre. Also the TeX code does many times the same thing.

Comment: @Denis I noticed the increase in pages on the pdf file, I have it set to `Use exported objects size` so unsure why it's happening. Seems maybe the components are being split to different pages for some reason?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a user of Inkscape. I just wanted to point out that your code (or Inkscape(s) was producing a strange pdf file. If in a hurry, I would advise to extract from the pdf the image you want and then to include it as an image.

Comment: @Denis no worries. The figure seems to be working fine, minus my last remaining issue of the white box around the figure labels. Idealy it'd scale with the text box.